# Calculate number of UITableViewCells that will fit in fixed space

Tags: ios, swift

I have a fixed amount of space where I will have a UITableView. I don't want the UITableView to scroll so I want to calculate the number of cells that will fit without scrolling. The cells are all different sizes and use UITableViewAutomaticDimension to determine size. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method and keep your cells heights in a dictionary then you can run a cicle over your dictionary values and sum all your keeped values, and do what you need with the values, let see some example code,

first define dictionary to keep your values

```
var automaticDimensionsHeightRows : [Int:CGFloat] = [:]
```

I defined this `var automaticDimensionsHeightRows` variable because I have 2 types of cells ones with fixed height and others with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`height

Then with this method we get, and keep the values

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if((self.tableView.delegate?.tableView!(self.tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath))! == UITableViewAutomaticDimension)
    {
        self.automaticDimensionsHeightRows[indexPath.row] = cell.frame.size.height
    }
}
```

Finally you can run a cicle over your dictionary values and check your values or do whatever you need to do

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want tableView to scroll just get visible cell of tableView
let arrayCell = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleItems()
or 
let arrayCells = tableView.visibleCells()

once you get visible cell you can find number of cell are visible